# Alias in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make this work, I read something about using subqueries, but still not working:
I like to use hwere clause with PRECIOFINAL alias.

```
select 
    NAME,
    PRICE,
    URL,
    STOCK,
    DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE,
    (PRICE-(PRICE*DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE/100)) as PRECIOFINAL 
from PRODUCT P 
left JOIN IMAGE I 
    on P.ID = I.PRODUCT 
left join PROMOTION PR 
    on PR.PRODUCT=P.ID 
where PRECIOFINAL >= 2 
    and PRECIOFINAL <= 20 ;
```

Thank you!

I want to do:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXPyF.png)

Price between 2 - 20 or must show me 3 items, but if it is 10-20 just 1 item because it has discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use alias in `WHERE` clause instead you can write sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
     NAME,
     PRICE,
     URL,
     STOCK,
     DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE,
    (PRICE-(PRICE*DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE/100)) as PRECIOFINAL 
  FROM 
  PRODUCT P left JOIN IMAGE I on P.ID = I.PRODUCT 
  LEFT JOIN PROMOTION PR on PR.PRODUCT=P.ID
)
WHERE PRECIOFINAL >= 2 and PRECIOFINAL <= 20;
```

Comment: I'd tried it, but still not working... Ty for the answer!

Comment: @Jose did you just copy pasted the query ??? what do you mean by not working..?? what error are you getting ?

Comment: Hi!! Sorry for not answering you, it was testing... your subquerie works fine, i was my problem... I'm trying to PRICE - PRECIOFINAL and i didnt realize that if I substract PRICE(number) - PRECIOFINAL(could be a number or null) -> PRICE is gonna be null as well, that's the reason why I couldnt see the results! I'm trying to fix this...

Comment: @Jose You are supposed to accept the answer. please read how to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't use a column alias in the where clause, you can repeat your formula:

```
select 
    NAME,
    PRICE,
    URL,
    STOCK,
    DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE,
    (PRICE-(PRICE*DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE/100)) as PRECIOFINAL 
from PRODUCT P 
left JOIN IMAGE I 
    on P.ID = I.PRODUCT 
left join PROMOTION PR 
    on PR.PRODUCT=P.ID 
where (PRICE-(PRICE*DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE/100)) BETWEEN 2 AND 20;
```

Comment: Hi!! Sorry for not answering you, i was testing... your subquerie works fine. I'm trying to PRICE - PRECIOFINAL and i didnt realize that if I substract PRICE(number) - PRECIOFINAL(could be a number or null) -> PRICE is gonna be null as well, that's the reason why I couldnt see the results! I'm trying to fix this...